# How to securely store OAuth 2.0 credentials in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I'm using Firebase functions to connect with an API that uses OAuth 2.0 and I need a secure place to store sensitive credentials (the refresh token). However, the token needs to be generated on the fly, so I can't store it in an environment variable.

Where is the most secure place to store sensitive credentials in Firebase?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I typically keep such credentials in memory after it's been generated. That means that future invocations on the same container will use the same credentials, while on a new container my code will generate new credentials.

Comment: Hi Frank! Thanks for your response. When you say "in memory" do you mean like in the /functions directory? My original plan was to just generate the credentials and store them into a JSON file in my directory, but I was told that was unsafe by Firebase Support since it's not encrypted.

Comment: I'd just keep them in a variable that you define outside of the function. If the variable is not initialized, you have to load the token. If it *is* initialized, you can use its value. You can also store it on disk, but I don't seen an advantage here (all writable disk space in Cloud Functions is a RAM disk anyway).

Comment: On security: it sounds like you are generating the OAuth key in the Cloud Functions code, which is why I'd suggest keeping it in the image. If you pregenerate it elsewhere, you should use an environment variable to pass it into the Cloud Functions container.

Comment: Hi again Frank! I can do that, but I have two fears 1) is that someone told me from Firebase that the container that hosts my Cloud Functions isn't encrypted, if that's true then isn't it risky to put OAuth credentials (the refresh token) there? and 2) is that Firebase doesn't guarantee that state will be borrowed from a previous invocation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips) so I worry that this might result in having the user constantly having to re-authenticate when I redeploy functions or for whatever reason local global variables may be cleared by Firebase.

Comment: Also, yes you are right, I am generating the OAuth credentials in my Firebase function. I can't store them in an environment variable since as far as I know, that can only be done during the deployment. (It *is* possible to save the refresh token into an environment variable, but sometimes the refresh token gets invalidated when the user changes a password/disconnects an app/whatever so I'd have to constantly redeploy new refresh tokens!)

Comment: Frank? Still never figured out a good solution to this!! Would super appreciate your help!